# How to critique promotional videos?

Tags: producing

I want to start producing short promotional videos for products, services, events, etc.

I figure the first thing to do is:

- Know how to find examples of 3-5 minute promotional videos,
- Learn how to critique the how the video expresses it's message, and
- Access the cost required to produce the video.

Any suggested resources for learning to do this?

Answer (score 1):

A quick google and the **3rd result** is this article on [how to write a product review](http://www.clicknewz.com/1995/how-to-write-a-product-review/)...

Finding examples is easy, just do a youtube search or google "Canon 550d Video Review" or any other product event or service. Just add "video review" to the end.

I dont think you will find any specific tutorials or resources on how to produce review videos. Making good review videos comes from experience. Either because the producer has been educated in writing & marketing or because they have done it many times before and have worked out what 'works' and what doesnt. Just look at the reviews that are already out there  and model yourself off those.

Cost is simple: What equipment do you need?

- Camera
- Lights
- Microphone
- Editing Software (eg Final Cut)
- Editing Hardware (eg Laptop)

Comment: I don't think "video review" is the same thing as a promotional video. Might do better with "promo"